# Distinguish if users accessing url from LAN or WAN (nginx)

Tags: nginx, web-server

Is it possible to distinguish between two users (with unknown IPs) that access the same URL, one from the internet (WAN) and one from the local LAN? If not, is it generally not possible or does it depend on the network hardware configuration?

My goal is to make a website available to all users within the local network, but require a client certificate to access the website from outside (internet). A workaround would be to use two different URLs, but the user experience would benefit from a single URL.

Comment: How can the users of your LAN have unknown IP's?

Comment: Your LAN, your addresses. You know them all. If user comes from any other address range than this, it's WAN. The only problem could be if your LAN users access your service through WAN IP and therefore being NATed twice for that; just don't do that, make LAN users access your server directly using server's LAN IP.

Comment: @vidarlo True, I forgot about IP ranges for local addresses *embarrassed*.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Yes, thank you.